# How to enumerate all events which a class declares?

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to be able to enumerate all events, which a class implements.

```
class A
{
    public delegate void X();
    public event X EventA;
}

class B:A
{
    public event X EventB;
}
```

What should I do to `typeof(B)` to get a list, which would consist of `EventB`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's the `Type.GetEvents` method, you should use it. If you only want events declared at B, and not inherited from A, pass `DeclaredOnly` as one of the binding flags.